# Django - Rollback is not happening when exception raised

Tags: python, django, transactions, atomic, django-database

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'diva',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'admin',
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS':True,
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
},
```

}

views.py

```
def create_project(self, request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
               code here
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception--->",str(e)
        response = {"status":"failed",'response': ugettext("projects.services.create_project.failure")}
        stat = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        return Response(response, status=stat)
```

in my code, if it raises ObjectDoesNotExist Exception rollback is not happening, can anyone explain how transactions work in django with example.

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct. Behaviour django will rollback a transaction, if an exception occurs but that exeption has to be a [DatabaseError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#django.db.DatabaseError) or one of it's subclasses (most notably IntegrityError)

The `ObjectDoesNotExist` is not a subclass of DatabaseError and as such there is no reason for this transaction to be rolled back.

last but not least. Don't catch `Exception` always catch the specific exception that you are looking out for.

Comment: Ouch! I'm glad I read this before I got bitten. Anyone know, why Django persists DB changes in this circumstance?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @e4c5. I need to rollback the entire transaction if any exception raised in my code and also able to send my own response from the view. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Sorry I seemed to have missed your comment. Just ran across this when going through some old answers. Do you still need help or is this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple databases configured you might want to specify the database to use with the `using` parameter. By default it uses the "default" database

```
with transaction.atomic(using="custom-db"):
    # your logic that raises error
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic